# New to node and sequelize and getting a "Unhandled rejection TypeError: Vacation.create is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to seed data using sequelize in my node.js project.

The error I am getting is:

Unhandled rejection TypeError: Vacation.create is not a function

My node js app contains:

```
Vacation = require('./models/vacation.js');
var app = express();
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

sequelize.sync().then(function () {
  Vacation.create({
            // insert new user
                    name: 'Hood River Day Trip',
                    slug: 'hood-river-day-trip',
                    category: 'Day Trip',
                    sku: 'HR199',
                    description: 'Spend a day sailing on the Columbia and ' +
                            'enjoying craft beers in Hood River!',
                    priceInCents: 9995,
                    tags: ['day trip', 'hood river', 'sailing', 'windsurfing', 'breweries'],
                    inSeason: true,
                    maximumGuests: 16,
                    available: true,
                    packagesSold: 0
            },
            {
                    name: 'Oregon Coast Getaway',
                    slug: 'oregon-coast-getaway',
                    category: 'Weekend Getaway',
                    sku: 'OC39',
                    description: 'Enjoy the ocean air and quaint coastal towns!',
                    priceInCents: 269995,
                    tags: ['weekend getaway', 'oregon coast', 'beachcombing'],
                    inSeason: false,
                    maximumGuests: 8,
                    available: true,
                    packagesSold: 0,
            },
            {
                    name: 'Rock Climbing in Bend',
                    slug: 'rock-climbing-in-bend',
                    category: 'Adventure',
                    sku: 'B99',
                    description: 'Experience the thrill of rock climbing in the high desert.',
                    priceInCents: 289995,
                    tags: ['weekend getaway', 'bend', 'high desert', 'rock climbing', 'hiking', 'skiing'],
                    inSeason: true,
                    requiresWaiver: true,
                    maximumGuests: 4,
                    available: false,
                    packagesSold: 0,
                    notes: 'The tour guide is currently recovering from a skiing accident.'
        }).success(function (data) {
 console.log(data.values)
})
});
```

and my model vacation.js contains

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function (sequalize) {
 var Vacation = sequelize.define("Vacation", {
    name:               Sequelize.STRING,
    slug:               Sequelize.STRING,
    category:       Sequelize.STRING,
    sku:                    Sequelize.STRING,
    description:    Sequelize.STRING,
    priceInCents: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    tags: [Sequelize.STRING],
    inSeason:           Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    available:          Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    requiresWaiver: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    maximumGuests:  Sequelize.INTEGER,
    notes:                  Sequelize.STRING,
    packagesSold:   Sequelize.INTEGER,
    });
return {
    Vacation: Vacation
};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`vacation.js` exports and object with a `Vacation` property. This means the import:

```
Vacation = require('./models/vacation.js');
```

receives an object that has a `Vacation` property and no `create` property.

You should export `Vacation` directly:

**vacation.js**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize) {
  var Vacation = sequelize.define('Vacation', {
    // Model field definitions
  });
  return Vacation;
};
```